# database solution for very large table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am dealing with some performance issues whilst working with a very large dataset. The data is a pairwise distance matrix of ~60k entries. The resulting vectors have been generated in the following format:

`mol_a,mol_b,score, year_a, year_b
 1,1,1,year,year
 1,2,x,year,year
 1,3,y,year,year
 ...
 1,60000,z,year,year
 2,1,x,year,year
 2,2,1,year,year
 ...`

where mol_a and mol_b are unique molecules (INTs) and score is their jaccard/tanimoto similarity score (FLOAT/REAL) and year_a and b are dates (INT(4)) that are associated with mol_a and b respectively. Since this is a distance matrix the values are reflected across the diagonal ie

`0 1 2 3 
1 1 x y
2 x 1 z
3 y z 1`

The resulting file has ~3.6 billion rows and becomes a ~100GB sqlite3 db. It take about 10 hours to make using all the PRAGMA tweaks I have read and doing `executemany` in 5 million entry batches. I would love to throw away half of it while building the but I can't think of a good way of doing this without ending up building a (prohibitively) giant list in memory... It's constructed via 2 nested for loops:

`for i in MolList: 
     for j in MolList:
         a = calculate_score(i,j)
         write_buffer.append(a)`

Though the creation is slow it is not the prohibitive part, the actual analysis i want to do with it is.. I will be grouping things by year_a and year_b so I started creating an index on year_a, year_b and score to have a 'Covering Index' but the build is 13 hours in and occasionally using mass amounts of harddrive space on my c: drive (which is a small SSD vs the raid where the database is). The whole thing is running on 12 core workstation with 16GB of ram, Windows 7 on a 240GB SSD and data storage on a 1TB Raid 1 array (built in MoBo controller).

I have also been attempting to build a MySql database on a small little ubuntu server that I have (intel core duo 2ghz 4GB ram 128GB SSD) but the python inserts across the network are taking forever! and I'm not convinced I'll see any real improvements.

SQLite from what I've read seems like what I really wanted, essentially this would all be handled in Python memory if I had ~150GB of RAM at my disposal, but I needed a file based storage solution which seems like exactly what SQLite was designed for. However watching SQLite consume a pittance of memory and CPU while Disk IO bounces around 5MB/s chugs away makes me think that disk is just a bottleneck.

What are my options for streamlining this process on a single node (aka no Hadoop clusters at my disposal)? I'm a DB newb so please keep suggestions within the realm of possibility. Having never worked with datasets in the billions I don't quite know what I'm in for but would greatly appreciate help/advice from this sage community.

Comment: If you're just manipulating simple integers, are you sure an RDBMS is the best solution for storing them? You'd be surprised how far you can get with a simple, no-nonsense binary file format of your own construction, slinging large chunks of that into memory for processing as necessary. You'd also want to investigate using a faster Python runtime like [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) where possible.

Comment: @tadman well the scores are floats.. And I will be the first to admit that my knowledge of binary is near NULL. I was going down the RDBMS road because it seemed like the most apt off the shelf solution to handling this data. I agree that it is really overkill, I need no user managment etc. which is why SQLite seemed like such a good option.

Comment: I'd start with your data problem and work backwards to a solution instead of taking RDBMS as a given. You may find the only way out of this is a more custom approach unless you're prepared to throw ridiculous amounts of hardware at it. Floats can be neatly serialized into a binary file using some simple encoding or a small library for managing it like [Struct](http://pymotw.com/2/struct/).

Comment: @tadman i'll look into it, I think it will require a fair bit of learning on my part (self taught programming woes..) which i'm not afraid of but want to limit loosing the forest for the trees...

Comment: Totally understand here. There's several ways for storing and manipulating this data. If you've got the disk space, JSON files (optionally gzipped) might make more sense than coming up with a custom binary format. They're easy to read, write, and once loaded into Python, show up as plain old data structures. Focus on getting your algorithm correct and have a read/write module for handling storage. You can easily switch from database to some other format, or vice-versa, if you abstract it a little.

Comment: Did you increase [PRAGMA cache_size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm surprised this never got mentioned but there are some good python tools for speedy disk based data storage and retrieval. I thought i would post here to help others on similar quest.

The one I wound up using is PyTables: http://www.pytables.org/moin

It offers some impressive disk IO stats with great (optional) compression/decompression on the fly using the hdf5 (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) file format. It is distinctly NOT a relational DB and is intended to be used alongside large DB or as an intermediary for situations such as mine: LARGE, *hierarchical* data.

Another option that I think deserves mentioning that I didn't end up implementing is MongoDB with Monary. MongoDB is a nice and fast document DB and Monary is a nice module for taking queries directly to numpy objects. 
Here's a little write up about going from MongoDB --> Monary --> pandas dataframe:

http://alexgaudio.com/2012/07/07/monarymongopandas.html

In my case the disk IO wasn't the only bottle neck, it turns out doing a lot of defaultdict() lookups and updates was the slow step. I think I could speed this up considerably using numpy data structures but i'm a bit of numpy newb and i got the overall runtime down to 2.5hrs which is good enough.

Hope this helps someone wandering down the python path to bigger than memory datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. The simplest is to simply save the output in chunks instead (say save one file for all the 1st molecule 'distance' scores, a second file for the second molecule distances, etc., with 60,000 files in all). That would allow you to also process your work in batches, and then aggregate to get the combined result.

If that's not possible due to operations you need to do, you can perhaps sign up for a free Amazon Web Services Trial and upload the data to a Redshift server instance there, it has very good compression (>10x is common), is frighteningly fast for data analysis, and if you know SQL, you should be fine.

Comment: would splitting the files (into seperate sqlite3 db files i assume?) really add any performance gains? I suppose I could then have python launch multiple instances but it seems like since I am inherently going to be comparing values across large chunks of dataset it would be less efficient than a well indexed single file? please correct me if i'm wrong (which i probably am) . I'm looking into RedShift at the moment!

Comment: The gain would be that you now have your data in manageable chunks, so a single error (or power outage) would not corrupt the entire batch, and you could run it in parallel streams. IT might be more amenable to desktop-based analytic tools, that usually like to process things in memory. If you're performing very simple aggregations, I'd go with tadman's suggestion above.